# Why Do I not get the exact numbers of rows that I've fetched?

Tags: sql, plsql, cursors

I'm learning PLSQL since 3 months. Now I'm practicing explicit cursors. I have written a simple cursor and I've used the attribute %ROWCOUNT for query 5 rows of employees but I received only 4 employees on screen. Why?

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  CURSOR cur_emp IS
    SELECT e.employee_id, e.last_name, d.department_id, d.department_name
    FROM employees e
    JOIN departments d
    ON (e.department_id = d.department_id);

  v_emp_id employees.employee_id%TYPE;
  v_emp_name employees.last_name%TYPE;
  v_dept_id departments.department_id%TYPE;
  v_dept_name departments.department_name%TYPE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cur_emp;
    LOOP
      FETCH cur_emp
      INTO v_emp_id, v_emp_name, v_dept_id, v_dept_name;
      EXIT WHEN cur_emp%ROWCOUNT = 5;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EMPLOYEE ID: ' || v_emp_id || ' EMPLOYEE: ' ||
        v_emp_name || ' DEPARTMENT ID: ' || v_dept_id || ' DEPARTMENT NAME: ' ||
        v_dept_name);
    END LOOP;   
  CLOSE cur_emp;
END;
/
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop first checks the condition, so to write 4 employees, check the rowcount of the next one and exit the loop you have to put ROWCOUNT > 5,  ROWCOUNT = 6 or move the `EXIT WHEN` condition to after your call to `DBMS_OUTPUT`.